# New PC - Disk Spiking to 100%

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building

I've recently built a new PC. Everything's working great, except that when I turn on the PC the disk performance will spike to 100% for 2-3 minutes. It also spikes when I open any programs. The main processes causing this are:

- Windows Defender's Antimalware Service Executable
- Windows Search
- Chrome
- System (range, including chrome processes, and os processes)

I've tried the usual fixes for these processes, however any fix I implement has meant that other processes occupy the 100% disk space. I have several questions:

1. Exactly which drivers do I need to fully setup the HDD?
2. Could this be a hardware fault? I made sure to prevent static when building so there shouldn't be any shock damage.
3. Is the system meant to be doing this, or should disk performance be much lower?

Specs:

- Motherboard: Auros b360 Gaming 3 Wifi
- Processor: Intel core i7 8700k
- RAM: 16GB DDR4 Vengeance
- HDD: Seagate Barracuda 4TB 3.5"
- GPU: Geforce 1060
- Power: Corsair TX850M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a 5400rpm disk drive. It's not fast enough to keep up with your CPU. You need to get an SSD to load Windows and applications on. Keep the HDD for data.

Comment: Even faster HDDs are a bottleneck this days.

Comment: You're quite sure this is whats likely to be the problem? I'll buy one now if you don't think its going to be a software issue.

Comment: @LaurieBamber I see this on old laptops with slow disks that have less powerful CPUs than your i7. If you want to know whats going on before spending $100 on an SSD, you could down load the Windows Performance Toolkit from the SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've bought a 500GB Samsung 860 SSD, so will give that a try and see if the situation improves.